# Failed when installing pdo via pecl

Tags: php, pdo, centos, pecl

Environment :

1. Cent OS 6.9
2. PHP 5.4
3. nginx

I'm trying to install pdo, when executing

> pecl install pdo

I got error messages like this :

[image: Error Message 1]

[image: Error Message 2]

[image: Error Message 3]

[image: Error Message 4]

I have googled a lot, but I still don't get it. I need at least a pointer on where I should look, thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use PECL to install PDO, CentOS has RPMs already for it. Try `yum install php-pdo`. That said, why start a new project with such an old version of PHP?

Comment: I tried it too, but it returned an error message, the php-pdo only works on php 5.3 not 5.4 :(

Comment: what was the error? I have `php-pdo-7.1.5-1.el6.remi.x86_64` on a live box

Comment: Ah OK I see, it looks like your 5.4 install is a custom compile. Just install a new server and go to 7.1. :)

Comment: I cannot install the new php, I'm using the very old version of cakephp, and it cannot go beyond php 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to remove php 5.4 then reinstall using this link : [PHP 5.4 installation guide](https://gist.github.com/mywarr/5611352), thanks to [Alex Howansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453002/alex-howansky) for your help, reading your "custom compile" answer gave me an insight to reinstall it, and it works good now, I don't have to install the pdo extension via pecl.
Hopefully this will help everyone who's having the same problem as mine.